# What is the solution to UNIQUE constraint failed: Readers.Id Error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am developing a .net application with C# WPF. When I try to add new consecutive records without closing the window, I encounter the following error. While this error works fine when I try to add data with the EF Add and SaveChanges methods, it occurs when I use the DataAccess class I created. I think there is a problem with the DataAccess class. What should I do to fix this problem?

Exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.'
> "UNIQUE constraint failed: Readers.Id"

DataAccess Sınıfı

```cs
using Kütüphane_Otomasyonu.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Kütüphane_Otomasyonu.Services
{
    public class DataAccess : IDisposable
    {
        public LibraryDataContext Context;
        
        /// <summary>Veri tabanı işlemlerini yürütür.</summary>
        /// <param name="dataContext"> Kullanılacak veri tabanı bağlantısı</param>
        public DataAccess( LibraryDataContext dataContext )
        {
            Context = dataContext;
        }

        /// <summary>Veri tabanından istenen kayıtları listeler</summary>
        /// <param name="includeProperties"> İstenen veriler</param>
        /// <returns> List</returns>
        public List<TEntity> GetAllKitaplar<TEntity>( params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includeProperties ) where TEntity : class
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = Context.Set<TEntity>();
            foreach( var includeProperty in includeProperties )
            {
                query = query.Include( includeProperty );
            }
            return query.ToList();
        }

        /// <summary>Veri tabanına kayıtları ekler </summary>
        /// <param name="entity"> Eklenecek entity</param>
        public void Add<TEntity>( TEntity entity ) where TEntity : class
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Add( entity );
        }

        /// <summary>Veri tabanındaki kayıtları günceller</summary>
        /// <param name="entity"> Güncellenecek entity</param>
        public void Update<TEntity>( TEntity entity )
        {
            Context.Entry( entity ).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        /// <summary>Veri tabanından kayıtları kaldırır</summary>
        /// <param name="entity">Kaldırılacak entity</param>
        public void Remove<TEntity>( TEntity entity ) where TEntity : class
        {
            Context.Set<TEntity>().Remove( entity );
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            Context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public static bool AnyNumber<TEntity>( Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate ) where TEntity : class
        {
            using( var Db = new LibraryDataContext() )
            {
                return !Db.Set<TEntity>().Any( predicate );
            }
        }

        public TEntity FirstAllDefault<TEntity>( Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate ) where TEntity : class
        {
            return Context.Set<TEntity>().FirstOrDefault( predicate );
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Context.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

//Veri ekleme
private void SaveExecute()
{
    NewReader.ClassId = 1;
    NewReader.ProfileId = 1;

    if( validationHelper.Count < 1 )
    {
        using( DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess( new LibraryDataContext() ) )
        {
            dataAccess.Add( NewReader );
            dataAccess.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

//Sorunsuz kod defalarca ekleniyor
using( var Db = new LibraryDataContext() )
{
    Reader newReader = new Reader
    {
        Active    = true,
        Name      = "example Reader",
        Surname   = "Example Reader",
        ClassId   = 1,
        ProfileId = 1,
        Gender    = Gender.Erkek,
    };

    Db.Readers.Add( newReader );
    Db.SaveChanges();
}

//DataContext
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Kütüphane_Otomasyonu.Models
{
    public class LibraryDataContext : DbContext
    {
public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Publisher> Publishers { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Reader> Readers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
public virtual  DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=Data\Database.db;";
            
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
        }

        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
                
    }
}

//Reader
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using Kütüphane_Otomasyonu.Enums;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Kütüphane_Otomasyonu.Models
{
    public class Reader : ObservableObject
    {
        private int _ıd; // Kimlik (ID) numarası: Okuyucunun benzersiz kimliğini temsil eder.
        private int _readerNumber; // Okuyucu Numarası: Okuyucunun numarasını temsil eder.
        private string _name; // Adı: Okuyucunun adını temsil eder.
        private string _surname; // Soyadı: Okuyucunun soyadını temsil eder.
        private Gender _gender; // Cinsiyet: Okuyucunun cinsiyetini temsil eder.
        private string? _address; // Adres: Okuyucunun adresini temsil eder.
        private string? _emailAddress; // E-posta Adresi: Okuyucunun e-posta adresini temsil eder.
        private DateTime? _birthDate; // Doğum Tarihi: Okuyucunun doğum tarihini temsil eder.
        private string? _phoneNumber;
        private DateTime _membershipDate;
        private string? _notes;
        private bool _active; // Aktif Durumu: Okuyucunun etkin olup olmadığını belirten bir mantıksal değer. (true veya false)
        private ICollection<OduncKitap> _oduncKitaplar;
        private Profile _profile;
        private Class _class;
        private int _profileId;
        private int _classId;

        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get => _ıd; set => SetProperty(ref _ıd, value); }

        public int ReaderNumber { get => _readerNumber; set => SetProperty(ref _readerNumber, value); }

        public string Name { get => _name; set => SetProperty(ref _name, value); }

        public string Surname { get => _surname; set => SetProperty(ref _surname, value); }

        public Gender Gender { get => _gender; set => SetProperty(ref _gender, value); }

        public string? Address { get => _address; set => SetProperty(ref _address, value); }

        public string? EmailAddress { get => _emailAddress; set => SetProperty(ref _emailAddress, value); }

        public DateTime? BirthDate { get => _birthDate; set => SetProperty(ref _birthDate, value); }

        public string? PhoneNumber { get => _phoneNumber; set => SetProperty(ref _phoneNumber, value); } 

        public DateTime MembershipDate { get => _membershipDate; set => SetProperty(ref _membershipDate, value); } 

        public string? Notes { get => _notes; set => SetProperty(ref _notes, value); }  

        public bool Active { get => _active; set => _active = value; }

        public virtual ICollection<OduncKitap> OduncKitaplar { get => _oduncKitaplar; set => SetProperty(ref _oduncKitaplar, value); } 

        public int ProfileId { get => _profileId; set => SetProperty(ref _profileId, value); }

        public virtual Profile Profile { get => _profile; set => SetProperty(ref _profile, value); } 

        public int ClassId { get => _classId; set => SetProperty(ref _classId,value); }
        public virtual Class Class { get => _class; set => SetProperty(ref _class, value); } 
    }
}
```

Comment: From the code you have posted, we don't see where there is a UNIQUE constraint. There must be either an attribute in your model or code in `OnModelCreating` indicating where there is a UNIQUE constraint. You can also search for it in the schema of you database.

Comment: Hello
Actually, there is no additional code in the OnModelCreating method and DataContext class other than SQLite database configuration. But if you wish, I can share that part too. But when I added it with the EF Add-SaveChange methods, there was no problem, but I couldn't understand why it threw an error when I added it with my special DataAccess class. At this point, I think there is a deficiency in the DataAccess class.

Comment: Are you creating a brand new entity every time you call add? or are you just updating the same one?  That may give you a unique constrain problem.

Comment: Hello
Now I did more detailed testing. It's not something related to the DataAccess class. This error occurs when I take the data from the controls on the WPF XAML (View) side and try to save the newReader object that I store in the ViewModel. Since the newReader.Id property remains the same after the SaveChanges call, it gives an error and the new automatic Id is not reflected in the newReader.Id property. The Id value in the database is set to increase automatically. What could be the solution?

Comment: "What should I do to fix this problem?" Do you understand what the message means? **Exactly** what do you think should happen instead, when the code runs, step by step? Do you understand what a UNIQUE constraint is, why they are useful, and why they might or might not be desired?

Answer (score -1):

Your code doesn't make things very clear but this method sends off some warning flags:

```
private void SaveExecute()
{
    NewReader.ClassId = 1;
    NewReader.ProfileId = 1;

    if( validationHelper.Count < 1 )
    {
        using( DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess( new LibraryDataContext() ) )
        {
            dataAccess.Add( NewReader );
            dataAccess.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

NewReader appears to be a module-level variable which says to me that the second time you call this method thinking you are adding a new instance it is going to be populated with data from a previous call. Even if you detach the instance somewhere else in the code, this is going to be problematic. An Add method should always create a new instance in-scope and not use module level variables. If the WPF view/user control is bound to an instance, then use a ViewModel class to handle the binding, don't bind to an entity directly. Entities should have no view-based concerns like NotifyPropertyChanged etc, let a view model be concerned with that. In this way when you go to add an entity, create a new instance, copy the values from the view model (after validating the view model) and then save that new instance.

Also check that if you are dealing with an existing database schema (rather that Code First & Migrations) that your Readers table's Id column is set to an Identity (Auto-increment) if an Int, or default to NewId/NewSequentialId if GUID) Then make sure that your entity configuration is set to recognize the Id as an Identity column. EF will configure this automatically by default with columns named "Id" or "ReaderId" in this case, but check that nothing has overridden the `DatabaseGeneratedOption` for this column either by an attribute in the entity or the entity configuration. It doesn't hurt to explicitly set PKs to Identity columns in the entity:

```
public class Reader
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    // ....
}
```

I recommend marking Id setters as `protected` to guard against code that might explicitly try to set these values. EF should be managing them solely.

Edit: The NewReader property should be a ViewModel class not an Entity. The problem with the SaveExecute/dataAccess.Add is that you are passing this single reference to be added to the DbContext. Once you do that, the DbContext is tracking that reference, so any changes you make to its properties will be tracked as modifications to that record, despite you calling Add again.

As a simple fix, in the SaveExecute method:

```
    using( DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess( new LibraryDataContext() ) )
    {
        var reader = new Reader 
        {
             // copy values from NewReader
        };
        dataAccess.Add( reader );
        dataAccess.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This will at least ensure that each added record is a separate object instance as far as EF is concerned. Ideally NewReader should be a view model class, not an entity.  Many examples demonstrate things like binding views to entities directly, and while it works Ok in very simple scenarios, it quickly falls apart leading to problems with tracking references.

Comment: Hello
Actually, appearance and appearance model are different. The NewReader property holds the bound values on the view side. My goal is to add the second, third or even fourth different records without closing the window. But when I try to save using Add and SaveChange, it throws an error during the second save.

Comment: Yes, and that is part of the problem, you are trying to re-add the same object reference `dataAccess.Add( NewReader );` Start by having this code create a new instance of a Reader entity and copy the appropriate values into that instance and add that Instance rather than always the same NewReader instance. Once you "add" it, EF's DbContext will be tracking it. The other point is you are mixing view concerns (bindings) with data concerns (entities) Ideally you should keep these as separate classes. They will have many of the same properties declared but focus on what the view vs. database need.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a change you can make to address the problem.

Comment: Please read [answer]; do not attempt to answer debugging questions that are blatantly missing a proper [mre] or any other evidence of attempts to understand the problem; and do not try to do code review here (there's a separate SE site for that). Answers are expected to answer the question directly, which requires that the question makes sense and contains everything necessary to make it answerable directly - so that Q&A here can serve the purpose described in the [tour]. Above all else please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: People come here for help with problems, not criticism that they don't understand how to ask a question. So if you have something constructive to add, do so, If you want to play moderator-wannabe, please do it elsewhere.

Comment: Hello
As you said, I created a new reader object in the using block and tried it. But I keep getting errors. Here's the thing: when I define the object manually, many error-free recordings are made. But the NewReader object connected to the xaml side is saved only once. It throws an error on the second operation. I couldn't find the solution to this problem. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What errors are you getting if you create a new Reader object populated by the bound NewReader? Just remember you cannot call `.Add(NewReader)` at any time.  Only add new Reader instances that you populate when saving. Think of it this way, once you add NewReader to the DbContext EF will be pointing NewReader at a row in the database. If you then make changes to NewReader EF will be thinking you want to alter that row, which is not what you intend.

Comment: Hello
Can I ask something like this?
My goal is to save the NewReader object to which the controls on the xaml side are connected as much as I want without closing the window. Can you share me an example on this subject? Because my code keeps throwing the Reader.Id error when trying to save more than one.

Comment: The simple fix to the SaveExecute mentioned near the end of my answer is just that. Don't ever add NewReader to the DbContext, always create a new Reader entity and copy the current values from NewReader into that, and add that copy. If you ever read the "NewReader" instance from the DbContext, read it with `.AsNoTracking()` in the query.,